# How to set SNC parameters for node-rfc?

Tags: node.js, saprfc

I am trying to use node-rfc to perform CRUD operations. The system I am trying to use has a SNC.

I do not know how to explain it well but SNC is a multifactor authentication.

I am using following parameters

```
var abapSystem = {
    sncName: 'p/secude:CN=<SYSTEM>,O=<COMPANY>,C=US',
    ashost: 'something.db.com',
    sysnr: '00',
    client: '400',
    SNC_MODE: '1'
};
```

and getting an error

> Invalid arguments supplied for SNC-API call

Does anyone know how to set it up?

Full code:

```
var rfc = require('node-rfc');
var abapSystem = {
    user: 'sap_user',
    passwd: 'sap_user_pwd',
    ashost: 'sap.nodomain',
    sysnr: '01',
    client: '800'
};
var client = new rfc.Client(abapSystem);
var MAX_ROWS = 3;
var SELECTION_RANGE_str = {
               PARAMETER: "USERNAME",
               SIGN:      "I",
               OPTION:    "CP",
               LOW:       "A*"
        };     
var SELECTION_RANGE_tab = [SELECTION_RANGE_str];

client.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('could not connect to server', err);
    }  
    client.invoke('BAPI_USER_GETLIST', {
                       MAX_ROWS: MAX_ROWS,
                       SELECTION_RANGE: SELECTION_RANGE_tab
        },
        function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error('Error invoking BAPI_USER_GETLIST:', err);
            }
               console.log('Result BAPI_USER_GETLIST:', res);
        });   
});
```

Comment: Make sure you provide details about what you tried, what you expect vs what's happening, and where you are stuck.  Explain it as if you are speaking to someone who has no idea what SNC is and you'll reach a broader audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not know how to explain it well but SNC is a multifactor authentication

SNC is not a multifactor authentication. Period.

Read [help](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nwpi71/7.1/en-US/07/7bfc3d86ff492e9f2ac8a522d56161/frameset.htm) thoroughly, it is SSO SAP technology with encryption.

I suppose the parameters should be following in your case:

```
var abapSystem = {
    'snc_mode' : '1',
    'snc_partnername': 'p/secude:CN=<SYSTEM>,O=<COMPANY>,C=US',
    'snc_lib': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SECUDE\\OfficeSecurity\\secude.dll',
    'sysid': 'SDC',
    'ashost': 'something.db.com',
    'sysnr': '00',
    'client': '400',
    'lang': 'EN',
    'trace': '3'
};
```

See [help](http://sap.github.io/node-rfc/authentication.html) for more details.

Also consider [this thread](https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC/issues/87#issuecomment-440267463) (born from [this](https://github.com/SAP/node-rfc/issues/81)) and SAP notes in it, some additional configuration is required in SAP backend. node-rfc was built on [the same binaries](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/nwrfcsdk.html) as PyRFC so adheres the same principles.

Comment: the following parameters worked for me
ashost: 'something.db.com',
    sysId: '<3 LETTER ID>',
    sysnr: '00',
    client: '400',
    lang: 'EN',
    snc_partnername: 'p/secude:CN=<SYSTEM>,O=<COMPANY>,C=US',
thank you! thanks for explaining SNC too :)

Comment: I think the parameter 'snc_mode' : '1' would also be required in order to turn SNC on. Or does PyRFC set this automatically, when it detects one of the SNC parameters? I know that the underlying RFC library doesn't set it automatically.

Also you may need 'snc_qop' : '9' in order to get the highest security (encryption plus digital signature).

Comment: fair point, i suppose we missed it with OP, added now. thanks. Security pars are dependent on asker system settings, so it is up to him to adjust them